# Finding folder sizes if i have hierarchy of folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to get the folder sizes exactly..
my folders are arranged like this

[image: folder structure]

m using parent_folder_id for all the folders. if the folder is root folder parent_folder_id is nil. For sub folder parent_folder_id is successive folder/sub folder id. 
Now i want to display the folder sizes exactly i.e including the sub folder sizes. As its a unlimited hierarchy, i am little bit confusing to loop. i want to display sub folder sizes also.

Can any one suggest me the solution.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`acts_as_tree`](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree/blob/master/lib/active_record/acts/tree.rb)

Add following method in your model

```
def all_children
  all = []
  self.children.each do |category|
    all << category
    root_children = category.all_children.flatten
    all << root_children unless root_children.empty?
  end
  return all.flatten
end
```

And then the call the method

```
@subfolder_children = @subfolder.all_children
```

Comment: `flatten` and `empty?` are unnecessary if you construct it better: `def all_children; children.each_with_object([]) {|child,result| (result << child).concat child.all_children }; end`